# Best way to ping client

Tags: php, unix, network-programming

Right, I have a **PHP script** at work where the server ping's a client.  The problem I am facing is that sometimes the server cannot contact the client although when I manually ping the client it ping's successfully.

The ping command I am using is this `ping -q -w 3 -c 1 < ipaddresshere >`

What would be the best way of pinging the clients maybe **2/3 times** leaving like a **2/3 second gap** if a ping fails before a retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are in the unix environment, you can always make and then call a shell script to handle the looping and waiting. But I'm surprised that  you can't do that inside of php.

Also, i'm not sure about your sample ping command, the 2 different environments I checked seem to have different meanings for the options you mention than what you seem to intend. Try `man ping` OR `ping --help`

The script below should give you a framework for implementing a ping-retry, but I can't spend a lot of time on it.

```
cat pingCheck.sh

#! /bin/bash -vx

IPaddr=$1

: ${maxPingTries:=3}
echo "maxPingTries=${maxPingTries}"

pingTries=0
while ${keepTryingToPing:-true} ; do
  if ping -n 3 -r 1 ${IPaddr} ;then
    keepTryingToPing=false
  else
    sleep ${sleepSecs:-3}
    if (( ++pingTries >= maxPingTries )) ; then
      printf "Execeeded count on ping attempts = ${maxPingTries}\n" 1>&2
      keepTryingToPing=false
    fi
  fi

done
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Says upvote requires 15 reps, great answer, thanks very much.  I will upvote when I get 15 reps.

Answer (score 0):

for php, you can try PEAR's Net_PING package.

here is a link guiding you through it
http://www.codediesel.com/php/ping-a-server-using-php/